# Understand why AWX suddenly requires sshpass

Tags: ssh, ansible, virtual-machine, ansible-awx, sshpass

I have been using an AWX server for some time for a project. I use AWX on standard virtual machine templates user root password root on which I always succeed to connect. Suddenly this morning the AWX tries to connect on one of the template in SSH and this error comes out : "to use the 'ssh' connection type with passwords or pkcs11_provider, you must install the sshpass program"
I tried to install sshpass on one of the templates but nothing changes, impossible to connect

I would like to be able to connect to my templates again

Answer (score 4):

I have been running the same issue, it seems that the latest version of awx-ee execution environment is buggy, as described in the [bug](https://github.com/ansible/awx-ee/issues/161)

Quick solution: Modify or create a new execution environment using the tag 2.11.0 instead of latest.

[image: Execution Environment edit page]